# I am using "table field/column" as varchar type not integer type. But why trimming first 0(zero)?

Tags: laravel, integer, trim, varchar

Here,
"Phone" is a field of "Employee" table and "Phone" type is string/varchar.

**Steps:**
**1)** Save one "Employee" information with **phone = "01679420786"**

**Migration:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('phone')->primary();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('designation');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Model:**

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'phone';
}
```

**2)** Get Employee and and then dd()

```
public function getEmployee()
{
    $employee = Employee::get();
    dd($employee[0]->phone);
    return view('employee.showEmployeeList')->with('employee', $employee);
}
```

**3)** Output in browser: **1679420786**

Using Laravel Framework 6.0.3, PHP Version: 7.3.2

Comment: Hi there, rather than posting links to images please provide the code within the question. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for giving suggestion.

Comment: Can you share the code for your `Employee` model?

Comment: Edited the post. And i added there model and migration code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the primary key of the model to `phone`. In this case it is a string. By default, Laravel is expecting this to be an integer and so is trying to cast the value to an integer. This is removing the `0` from the start of the value.

In order to solve this, add the following property to your model.

```php
protected $keyType = 'string';
```

This tells Laravel that the primary key is not an integer and it is instead a string, so it will cast it accordingly.

Your model should then look something like the following:

```php
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'phone';

    protected $keyType = 'string';
}
```